# How can I turn bash exec.Command returns into Arrays?

Tags: go

I'm trying to find files that end in `hello.go`

```
statement:= "find "CurrentDirectory" -print | grep -i hello.go"
result, error := exec.Command("bash", "-c", statement).Output()
```

This gives me a list containing 2 file paths and I try to turn them into arrays that I can individually address using:

```
Directory_array := strings.Split(string(result),"\n")

fmt.Println(len(Directory_array) )
```

The length of the array shows as "`3`" but the array is empty except for the 0th position.

Independently the code lines work but not together. How can I get the array to fill with individual paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, use `strings.FieldsFunc` instead of `strings.Split`. For example:

```
statement:= "find . -print | grep -i hello"
result, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", statement).Output()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ds := strings.FieldsFunc(string(result), func(r rune) bool {
    return r == '\n'
})
for i, d := range ds {
    fmt.Println(i, d)
}
```

Further reading:

1. [strings.FieldsFunc - go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#FieldsFunc)
2. [strings.FieldsFunc vs strings.Split - Medium](https://medium.com/@mlowicki/strings-fieldsfunc-vs-strings-split-96c667912f78)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the stdout pipe and read line by line using a [Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#NewScanner).

```golang
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-l")
    out, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    s := bufio.NewScanner(out)

    cmd.Start()
    defer cmd.Wait()

    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("new line:")
        fmt.Println(s.Text())
    }
}
```

If you want to store this into a slice, you can create the slice beforehand and append to it.

```golang
lines := make([]string, 0, 10)
for s.Scan() { lines = append(lines, s.Text()) }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have missed calling Run() in your code. Here is how to fix it:

```
statement:= "find "CurrentDirectory" -print | grep -i hello.go"
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", statement)
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    ...
}
result, error := cmd.Output()
```

P.S. Why not to use os.Walk()?

Comment: `Cmd.Output()` runs the command and returns its standard output. Your code will result in `exec: already started` error at line: `result, error := cmd.Output()`. https://go.dev/play/p/kPOSV9Y4Szo